# Notepad ++ regex: replace one or more text-value semicolon(s) with a dash, when semicolon is the field delimiter

Tags: notepad++, regex, csv

I am struggling a little bit.
The file I need to manipulate is a csv with semicolon as field delimiter.
In some datasets a comment was added which INCLUDES a semicolon. Luckily these comments begin and end with " .

Example:

```
;;;"sometext many words or few ; more text; even more text";;;;;;
```

I need to replace all semicolons between the ", but keep the text.
Thanks for helping me out.

Sample dataset:

```
Before Regex find & Replace:  
Fieldtitles: f1;f2;f3;f4;f5;f6;f7;f8;f9;f10;f11  
Dataset1: ;;text;text;;text;text;text;text;text;text  
Dataset2: text;"text text text ; text text";text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text

After Regex find & Replace:  
Fieldtitles: f1;f2;f3;f4;f5;f6;f7;f8;f9;f10;f11  
Dataset1: ;;text;text;;text;text;text;text;text;text  
Dataset2: text;"text text text _ text text";text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text
```

Comment: Please share sample from original file and expected output.

Comment: If your goal is to load the csv file into excel, edit the csv file with notepad, and add the following row to the start: `sep=;` now you can load it into excel without any problems.

Comment: @LPChip: Thank you, this works for excel-display. But I need to normalize for DB import, table has 150k rows, would prefer a solution which uses RegEx F&R

Comment: You may be able to get it normally in excel first, then search/replace in there. I know, this is not an answer, but its a workaround, and if it's a one-time only, it may be your escape.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `"[^";]*\K;(?=[^";]*")`
- Replace with: `_`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
"           : a double quote
[^";]*      : 0 or more any character that is not a double quote or a semicolumn
\K          : forget all we have seen until this position
;           : a semicolumn
(?=         : start lookahead, make sure we have, after current position,
  [^";]*    : 0 or more any character that is not a double quote or a semicolumn
  "         : a double quote
)           : ed lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
_       : an underscore
```

**Result for given example:**

```
Fieldtitles: f1;f2;f3;f4;f5;f6;f7;f8;f9;f10;f11  
Dataset1: ;;text;text;;text;text;text;text;text;text  
Dataset2: text;"text text text _ text text";text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text;text
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Replace window, specify the following:

- Find What: `\"(.*?);(.*?)\"`
- Replace with: `"\1_\2"`
- Check the `Regular Expression` radio bullet.

This will replace `;` with `_` in comments that include one semicolumn.
Regex breakdown:

- `\"` - Start matching from double quotes
- `(.*?);` - match everything until the first semicolumn
- `(.*?)\"` - match everything until the next double quotes
- `"\1_\2"` - output the matched double quotes and matched subexpressions #1 and #2, while replacing `;` with `_`.

If it's possible to have multiple semicolons in a comment, just keep hitting `Replace All` (with the `Wrap around` option checked) - it will replace one semicolon per comment at a time, until all semicolons are replaced.